# How to retrieve multi media stored in sql server using c#?

Tags: c#, database, multiple-columns

I am working on a windows desktop application using c#. In my project, i want to show video in windows media player component and i stored my video in sql server. (I inserted my video files in varbinary(max) column and i dont want stored file path in database!!!)

I want to retrieve video from database and play video in windows media player.
How can i retrieve video?

my inserted code:

```
private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDlg.InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    if (openFileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(openFileDlg.FileName);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] fileData = rdr.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        rdr.Close();
        fs.Close();

        Context databse = new Context();
        tblvideo tv = new tblvideo();
        tv.videoName = fi.Name;
        tv.Video = fileData;
        databse.tblvideos.Add(tv);
        databse.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Playing Audio and Video File in Windows Form Application: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/26b237/playing-audio-and-video-file-in-windows-form-application/

Comment: thanks, I check it. if work correctly mark your answer

Comment: thanks it work correctly

Answer (score 0):

If the application can ever be accessed online, your limiting the option to view the video from someones local machine, whereas if you host it on a CDN (like maxcdn) then you can just reference that external link in your code.